# How to get original ip instead of proxy's IP in TCP?

Tags: c, networking, linux-kernel, network-programming, netfilter

There are three host, clients A, Proxy B and Server C:

A->B->C.

In this example, how can I get A's IP address on server C?

This is TCP protocol.

Comment: What kind of proxy?

Comment: A transparent proxy. It's just forward A's packets to Server C.

Comment: I have a idea, I don't know whether  it is feasible.  To change Proxy B's src ip to Client C's  on Server C

Comment: “It's just forward A's packets to Server C.” — If it does so without NAT, then the packets will arrive with A’s address intact. You want to disable NAT or use something like proxy ARP to connect A and C.

Comment: You mean a router? (without NAT)

Comment: I have a secure product, client A connect to server C via proxy B. I need to obtain real client ip, and some applications(http, mysql ...) need using real client ip on server C.

Comment: Which one is inside of the proxy, A or C?